# Setting attribute table cell heights in print composer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, print-composer

Is it possible (and how) to set the attribute table cell heights in print composer in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like there's a way to directly specify row height. You can indirectly change row height by:

- Changing the font size under Item Properties > Fonts and Text Styling > Table Contents.
- Changing the cell margin width under Item Properties > Appearance.